# React.js/Solid.js Import path fallback index.js alternative

Tags: reactjs, import, solid-js

You can import file using `index.js` naming and pointing to folder where is that file.

```
- src
   App.js
  - Component
     index.js
```

And when importing it will fallback to `index.js`

```js
import Component from './Component'
```

Can I write the same but remaining file named as folder?

Answer (score 0):

Both React and Solid follows JavaScript's import and export semantics and there are no extra rules or workarounds.

In JavaScript, pointing to a file or folder has no effect, you have to import and export items explicitly and there is no built-in fallback mechanism.

You can learn more about ES6 module rules at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules.